# How to send request(String data) from android to PHP server localhost and receive response result form server PHP

Tags: java, php, android

**This is my PHP code**

[image]

**This is my Android code**

[image]

Example: String data is a first program ( the Hello world is written on Java Code).

I want to send String data from android to server PHP(picture 1). Server PHP will compile Java code and return result and my android application will receive response result from server PHP. Please help me!

Comment: you can use the library for making networking calls eg Retrofit, Volley as they provide easy to handle Callbacks and make the task easier

Comment: `NameValuePair` is deprecated in api 23. Use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your code should be provided as text and not image, so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can send json or xml format data to php server it will give data in json or xml format,